# why when I press (trigger the OnClick) it doesnt work but when it written outside the onclick it does work

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhzKT.png)
why when I press (trigger the OnClick) it doesnt work but when it written outside the onclick it does work? (OnClick of the  and the function one line after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add parentheses at the end of a function name, you are indirectly invoking them at the time they are parsed in the browser. Therefore, trying removing the parentheses and it should work as expected.

EDIT: Newer Answer

So, what you can do is, use setState to change what the user should see at any point of time. Initially, that will be the default screen and then when the user click the image it will be deck screen. So your useState will look something like this:

```
const [screenName, setScreenName] = useState("default");
```

Now that you have this, store the two components i.e. your default screen with the image, and the deck screen with cards.map().... into two separate components inside your original function of Gamepage.js. The return of this(the main) function should look like the following:

```
return(<>{
    screenName === "default" ? <DefaultComponent /> : <DeckComponent />
}</>);
```

After doing this, you just make a small change to the onClick of the DefaultComponent so that it does the following:

```
setScreenName("deck");
```

This should do the job, lmk if you need any further help.

Comment: I have already tried it and it doesn't work... maybe because this function is moving things on screen and it doesn't re-render to show the change ? but on the other hand, the function outside the onClick does not either... I'm kinda lost here

Comment: Ah well, now I get what you are trying to do. I will add my answer below my original one.

Comment: sounds good I'll try this rn and let you know if it worked

Comment: I am glad it all worked out!